# Notification does not play sound in iPad and android device

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel-5

I am working on system which require sound notification when new store is made.I am all right with AJAX part, sound works when I have open my system in PC, but does't work when I tried in a iPad with Chrome and Safri, even in a Android device with Google Chrome, is my code not ok, or it is not supportable in other devices?

My code:

```
if(typeof(EventSource) !== "undefined") {

var source = new EventSource($('meta[name="base_url"]').attr('content') +'/notification_ajax');
var audio = new Audio('assets/file.mp3');

source.onmessage = function(event) {

    var myarr = event.data.split(",");

    if(parseInt(myarr[1]) !=  parseInt(myarr[0])){
        audio.play()
        var url = $('meta[name="base_url"]').attr('content') +'/update_file';
        $.ajaxSetup({
            headers: {
                'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            }
        });
        $.post(url,
            {old_count: myarr[1]
            },
            function (data) {

            })

    };
}}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you checked it on all the android device with chrome?

Comment: @AlbertAkki I can not check it with all the android devices because it is impossible, I have tried it 3.

Comment: Just go to the mobile chrome site setting > sound option. is it enabled there? in mobile device.

Comment: @AlbertAkki yes it is checked.